# Solution Explorer: limit search to selected folder

Tags: visual-studio, solution-explorer

A question of efficiency, when looking for a file within specific sub-folder of a project, how can I limit the search in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer just to the selected folder(s)?

---

Typing query in Solution Explorer's will search *all* projects and *all* folders, giving vast majority of false positives and rendering its search box effectively useless.
The only way I am aware of right now is to `RMB -> Open Folder in File Explorer ->` type query in Windows Explorer search box, then go back to Visual Studio and manually scroll to the file knowing its exact name. Needless to say, exiting IDE for something as simple as file search is not very convenient.

Comment: Or in other words, I would like something similar to Filter option in SQL Management Studio (preferably with less clicks to access).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Solution Explorer, right click on the concerning folder and select "Scope To This"; now that folder becomes the root of your Solution Explorer and the search only applies to the visible content. You go back via the arrow buttons.

Comment: Bonus point: scope to multiple folders, is it possible somehow?